# 20 30 Die Split

Tags: probability

**Edit: Although there are similar questions, there is not one that answers this specific case where Bob retools after seeing only his own card, and calculates the corresponding probability.

Alice and Bob have fair 30 and 20−sided dice, respectively. The goal for each player is to have the largest value on their die. Alice and Bob both roll their dice. However, Bob has the option to re-roll his die in the event that he is unhappy with the outcome. He can't see Alice's die beforehand. Bob then keeps the value of the new die roll. In the event of a tie, Bob is the winner. Assuming optimal play by Bob, find the probability Alice is the winner.

My approach was as follows.

$\frac{1}{3}$ of the time, Alice rolls between a 21 and a 30. In this case, she always wins. The remaining $\frac{2}{3}$ of the time, she rolls between a 1 and 20. We must now find the probability that she wins in this case.

Since Bob can only see his die before choosing to reroll, he will only reroll in the event when he rolls less than 10.5, because the expectation for his roll is $\frac{20+1}{2} = 10.5$. So, if his initial roll is 1-10, he rerolls and obtains a 10.5 on average. In this case, Alice wins if her roll is between 11 and 20, so her chance of winning is $\frac{1}{2}$.

In the case when Bob rolls above a 10.5, his average roll is $\frac{11+20}{2} = 15.5$. Hence Alice would only win if she rolls between 16 and 20, so her chance of winning is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Combining these we get:

$P(Alice Wins) = \frac{1}{3} * (1) + \frac{2}{3}*(\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4})) = \frac{7}{12}$

This is slightly off from the answer of $\frac{17}{30}$

Comment: You cannot roll $10.5$ or $15.5$ and your calculation ignores the possibilities of ties (the probability would be different if Alice won ties instead of Bob)

Comment: If Bob's first roll is $11-20$ (probability $\frac12$) then the conditional probability he wins or ties with that score is $\frac{31}{60}$ not $\frac12$.   If Bob's first roll is $1-10$ (probability $\frac12$) then the conditional probability he wins or ties with his second roll is $\frac{21}{60}$ not $\frac13$.  So his probability overall of winning or tying is $\frac12\, \frac{31}{60} + \frac12\, \frac{21}{60} = \frac{52}{120}=\frac{13}{30}$ not   $\frac12\, \frac{1}{2} + \frac12\, \frac{1}{3} = \frac{52}{12}=\frac{5}{12}$.  This leaves $\frac{17}{30}$ not $\frac{7}{12}$ for Alice winning

Comment: Your expression for $P(\text{Alice wins})$ should be $\frac13 \times 1+\frac23\times \frac12(\frac{19}{40}+\frac{9}{40}) = \frac{17}{30}$